# creating a zip file in php without using ziparchive

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to create a zip file in PHP.

The server environment is limited so I can't use the [ziparchive](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) extension neither can `exec` a shell command.

Is there a pure php solution that would allow me to create .zip archives anyway?

Comment: I hope this would help you http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_zip.asp

Comment: @jolly.exe your solution uses the zip extension which i cant use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also PCLZip, a pure PHP alternative to ZipArchive that can be found at http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/

Comment: yeah i already tried pclzip , it fails compressing large files when it doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: I also found this just now but I found the question was closed: http://www.tinybutstrong.com/apps/tbszip/tbszip_help.html

Answer (score 1):

What is present on the server for sure?
If it's a Unix machine you maybe can exec a shell command? `shell_exec('zip ...')`

Comment: i cant use any shell command either

Comment: then you have to include some implementation into your project. just found this http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpzip/

Comment: yeah its pclzip , it has a problem with compressing large files, thanks anyway