# PHP zip archive undefined method setPassword

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using PHP 5.5.9. I need to download password protected zip file. I am using zip archive setPassword method. But its showing error undefined method setPassword. Can please anyone help me. Below I mentioned whatever I done.

```
$excelName = 'DownloadDocument_'.Carbon::now()->format('dmY');
$filename = storage_path('app/zipFolder/').'DownloadDocument_'.Carbon::now()->format('dmY').'.zip';
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) == TRUE) {
$zip->addFile(storage_path('app/fileFolder/').$excelName.'.xls', 'newname.xls');
$zip->setPassword("secret");
$zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Please post your question with whatever code you have done so far with a full trace of code snippet. People can not assument by just text question.

Answer (score 1):

The [ZipArchive::setPassword](http://php.net/ziparchive_setPassword) method only exists in PHP version 5.6.0 or higher. Since you are using PHP version 5.5.9 this method is not available in your PHP installation.

Comment: Then how to set password to zip file in php 5.5.9. Can anyone please help me to do this.

Comment: @Sriramulu You can use other libraries like on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309328/creating-a-zip-file-in-php-without-using-ziparchive or use `exec()` to call the `zip` program, assuming it is installed on the OS.